# Logout and redirect user back to login blade with a message on change password in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect, laravel-6

I'm trying to logout and redirect my user back to login blade once the user's password is changed successfully.

This is my controller so far (only the function is included),

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'current_password' => ['required', new MatchOldPassword],
            'new_password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:12', 'confirmed','regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{12,}$/'],
            'new_confirm_password' => ['same:new_password'],
        ]);

        User::find(auth()->user()->id)->update(['password'=> Hash::make($request->new_password)]);

        //dd('Password change successfully.');

    }
```

Here on success how can I logout and redirect my user back to login blade with a success message (Pass word has been changed. Please log in again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two solution to this problem. Simply add `with` function to create a flash message you wanted.

---

**Solution 1:** Go to the `AuthenticatesUsers.php` and inside the `logout` function change the redirected route from `/` to `/login`. (Assuming your using `make:auth`)

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    //more codes here

    return $request->wantsJson()
        ? new Response('', 204)
        : redirect('/login')->with('success', 'Password change successfully.');
}
```

---

**Solution 2:** Make a customed one. Create a controller function and add these following codes below:

```
public function logout()
{
    \Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/login')->with('success', 'Password change successfully.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can redirect to your logout function and return a session message to the login blade.

Answer (score 0):

Auth::logout();
return redirect('/login');

For showing a message you can use

https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr